# Dynamically pull news articles by year?

Tags: navigation, dynamic

I have a news section which is functioning like a blog. Currently in the navigation I am statically listing the years for which content was published. I would like to change this so that ExpressionEngine will automatically generate links to different years only if there are articles that were published that year.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<div class="content-tile">
  <div class="grid_4_desktop grid_4_tablet grid_1_mobile" id="archive-menu">
    <h2 class="title">News</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='{path=news/article/?latest=true}'   <?php if(isset($_GET['latest'])){echo 'class="active"';};?> >Latest Post</a></li>
      <li><a <?php if($year == '2013'){echo 'class="active"';}; ?> href="{path=news/?year=2013}">2013</a></li>
      <li><a <?php if($year == '2012'){echo 'class="active"';}; ?> href="{path=news/?year=2012}">2012</a></li>
      <li><a <?php if($year == '2011'){echo 'class="active"';}; ?> href="{path=news/?year=2011}">2011</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Can anyone tell me how I would change this code so that the years are automatically populated based on when articles were published?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [Yearlist Add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/yearlist)?

Then I would think it should be possible to do something like this:

```
<div class="content-tile">
<div class="grid_4_desktop grid_4_tablet grid_1_mobile" id="archive-menu">
    <h2 class="title">News</h2>
    <ul>
      {exp:yearlist channel="yourchannel" category="1"}
          <li><a href="{path=news/?year={years}}">{years}</a></li>
      {/exp:yearlist}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I need! Unfortunately when I replaced the code with the code above and put my channel name inside channel="" it is not displaying anything in the navigation now. Do I have to do anything other than copy the folder to the third_party folder to activate the plugin? Sorry, still new to EE.

Comment: Nevermind, I was using the name instead of the shortname for channel. Now it's displaying the menu, but instead of showing the year it just shows {year}. Any ideas?

Comment: Took a look at the usage documentation on https://github.com/ryanirelan/ri.yearlist.ee_addon.2.0 and realized that it's {years} instead of {year}. It's working perfect now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself [Zoo Triggers](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/triggers/) and you will love yourself!

```
{exp:zoo_triggers:archive channel="news" status="open" show_counter="no" type="year"}
```

Just make sure you give the [settings docs a once over](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/triggers/start/overview.html) to get it set up like you want.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like an awesome add-on, I will definitely check it out.